error C2011: 'HMONITOR__': 'struct' type redefinition
I was given a rather large old Project that I'm currently in the process of writing Cmake files for.
I have a complication now between windef.h and dxgi.h the Error occurse at the this code block.

#if !defined(HMONITOR_DECLARED) && !defined(HMONITOR) && (WINVER < 0x0500)
#define HMONITOR_DECLARED
#if 0
typedef HANDLE HMONITOR;

#endif
DECLARE_HANDLE(HMONITOR);
#endif


It is trying to redefine HMONITOR but it should just skip this If because the WINVER Variable is 0x0A00.
I've looked at different locations in the code if the headers are getting included in the wrong order. I'm expecting that it is a error with the Properties of my project and that the compiler is not understanding that it can skip that code segment. I just don't know what setting that could be or where i would need to look.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\dxgi.h(224,1): error C2011: 'HMONITOR__': 'struct' type redefinition
what is a good way to find out where this include is?

Probably, some macro has a value which you are not expecting. We know nothing about your project so we cannot help you in fixing that.

@Tsyvarev I'm not quite sure what i would need to show you so you could help me. would you need snippets from specific files or project configs?

What kind of help you expect from us? Just check in your project that macros are correctly passed to the compiler when it compiles your code.
